# tomcat hot deploy war file to live site

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7, war

From [this blog](http://agoodcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/tomcat-7-hot-deploy-rolling-upgrade.html) :

> All you need to do is to
>
> 1. keep your old app foo.war untouched
> 2. name your new version of app to foo##0001.war and upload to webapps folder
>
> The old session will use foo.war, and new user will use foo##0001.war.

Is that the best way to deploy a new version of your app without restarting the webserver ?And is the string literally correct, `myApp.war` would be replaced with `myApp##0001.war`, the string seems rather unusual.

Comment: Note: unless you've completely solved all of the memory leaks that lead to exhausting PermGen space upon redeploy, hot deploy will soon bring your server to a grinding halt.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart - this is solved in tomcat 7 right ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

> The version component is treated as a String both for performance
>   reasons and to allow flexibility in versioning schemes. String
>   comparisons are used to determine version order. If version is not
>   specified, it is treated as the empty string. Therefore, foo.war will
>   be treated as an earlier version than foo##11.war and foo##11.war will
>   be treated as an earlier version than foo##2.war. If using a purely
>   numerical versioning scheme it is recommended that zero padding is
>   used so that foo##002.war is treated as an earlier version than
>   foo##011.war.

So the string although unconventional seem to be what is expected.

But I was wondering: from Tomcat management you can deploy/undeploy web applications without restarting Tomcat. Can't you use that?

Comment: Using tomcat manager, will that maintain sessions ... ? Ie people will not get chucked off, but new visters will use new version ?

Comment: So you problem is not to restart tomcat.Is to keep your web application responsive?Well in that case you can't use tomcat manager.You are right.

Comment: whats the benefit of using tomcat manager if it doesn't maintain sessions/keep site responsive ?

Comment: It is for administration purposes.It doesn't suite what you seem to need (no downtime on redeploying an application)